# Open port 2525 on Google Cloud platform

Tags: linux, cloud, port

I'm trying to set-up a Postfix on my Google Cloud Virtual Machine and I'm trying to use the Postfix to receive/send/read emails trough the relay server offered by SendGrid. 
I followed this tutorial:https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail and set up the Firewall rules as following:

default-allow-mail
Logs 
Off
view
Networkdefault
Priority1000
DirectionEgress
Action on matchAllow
Destination filters
IP ranges
0.0.0.0/0
Protocols and ports
tcp:2525
EnforcementEnabled
Insights
None
Hit count monitoring 
—

The port 2525 it's still blocked according to this https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

My IP where I want the port 2525 open it: 34.66.224.92

Answer (score 0):

It looks like (sorry, formatting's a bit off) that you only set the egress rule to open 2525, but did you also set an ingress rule to open 2525?

Assuming I'm reading your entry correctly, you're only allowing outbound traffic on port 2525, but SendGrid sounds like it needs to have incoming traffic happening on 2525, right?

Comment: Yes I want inbound and outbound connections on port 2525.

Comment: Yeah, double-check your firewall. It looks like you only set a rule for egress, not ingress.

Comment: Just as an occam's razor... have you tried just running the Postfix setup with SendGrid and seeing if it works if you have the ingress rule opening port 2525 and not relying on the port tool?

Also double check that the firewall is applied to your GCE instance? You have network tags applied to your GCE instance, and they match the firewall apply rules?

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer, I have tried to run Postfix as relay for SendGrid. How to double check the firewall, what do you mean? As It is right now on the GCE Firewall table I see no tags.

Comment: So first thing to check, on the console if you go to VPC network -> Firewall, and check the firewall you made. Under Targets, is it "apply to all" or is there a named target? If it's a named target, that needs to be listed in the network tag for your VM instance. Look at the details for your GCE instance: Scroll down, you'll see a section for Network interfaces, then Public DNS PTR Record, then Firewalls, and then Network tags. That network tag has to match the Target in your firewall or your firewall isn't applied to that instance, and by default, all ingress ports are blocked for GCE VMs.

Comment: Hi Gabe, hope you're doing well. Thank you for your answer. All instances in the network. Still 2525 closed.

Comment: Hey Alex, we'll get there. ;) So, when you created the VM, did you create it in the default network (VPC)? Or did you create a separate VPC for it?